# Django admin - How to add request.user as default vaule for a Inline model?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've written a small support application made out of 2 models, please see below.
As I answere onto support tickets at the django admin panel, I dont always want to set the author name manully for each reply I add to the ticket. Instead I want that request.user I set as author automatically as initial vaule. Sadly I was not able to find any solution at the django docs that seem to solve this issue ...

admin.py

```
class SupportTicketRepliesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SupportTicketReplies
    extra = 0
    min_num = 1

class SupportTicketsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['requester', 'creation_date', 'status', 'category', 'subject']
    ordering = ['-creation_date']
    list_filter = ['creation_date']
    inlines = [
        SupportTicketRepliesInline,
    ]


admin.site.register(SupportTickets, SupportTicketsAdmin)
```

models.py

```
...
class SupportTickets(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    requester = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    category = models.IntegerField(choices=TICKET_CATEGORY, verbose_name='Ticket Category')
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=False, verbose_name='Problem description')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_OF_TICKET, verbose_name='Ticket Status', default=2)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)

    def publish(self):
        self.creation_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Support Ticket"
        verbose_name_plural = "Support Tickets"
        ordering = ['-creation_date']
```

models.py

```
class SupportTicketReplies(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ticket = ForeignKey(SupportTickets, related_name='replies', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Author', blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Content", max_length=2000)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Ticket Reply"
        verbose_name_plural = "Ticket Replies"
        ordering = ['creation_date']
```

[image: Screenshot - Django admin panel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "author":
        author = request.user
        if author:
            kwargs['initial'] = author.pk
    return super(SupportTicketRepliesInline, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

At a admin.TabularInline or admin.StackedInline

Answer (score 1):

i think everything what  you need is :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey
it will look smrh like:

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "author":
        self.fields['author'].queryset = UserModel.objects.filter(id=request.usermodel.id)
```

also you should remove blank=True from your model.

or you can just add to your inline class as initial value:

```
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.fields['author'].initial = self.request.user
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I tried your Solution but I always faild with the following error:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

This is my query:

self.fields['author'].queryset = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
Which returns the valid UUID, I can confirm on that!

Comment: User.objects.get(id=request.user.id) doesnt return queryset, but single object.

Comment: Then I simply dont get it ... Beside your solution points out to admin.ModelAdmin but im on admin.TabularInline

Comment: its also possuble use it in inlines.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-options

the point is, you limit your queryset to only logged in request.user. (so its one user) 
but still need to pass is as queryset.(si .filter is required)

Comment: Did you saw my solution?

Comment: right now you can select other options from the select box.... if you dont want to do it, you must limit the queryset...

and yes i saw your code. you dont need to query User... its returned by request.user .... also check if exists is useless.. (in your code ... .get would return error if not exists....)